# Can't see how to tell Maven to install jars on lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

Sorry if this is too trivial, but I've recently jumped into Wep Applications from standard console java projects, and since in java projects I successfully used maven to download jars and include them into the classpath... in the web app I don't know how to accomplish the same stuff and downloading to the lib folder on WEB-INF instead of just adding the jars to my classpath.

I have searched stack overflow and the google for an answer, but since I haven't found any single answer, I'm afraid I should be completely wrong with my approach for this.

I have just created my webapp on eclipse, then converted it to maven project, and then added this dependencies in pom.xml, as I used to do in a normal java project:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
             <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Everything seems to be ok, and no error is shown, but the jars are not downloaded into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: did you package the webapp and try it out without errors? Maven will not download then into the lib folder, but will copy them into the lib folder during the package phase, so your final war will properly provide them

Comment: No. I didn't, Di Matteo. And thanks, 'cause now I start to understand the reasons for maven to donwload first to Maven dependencies folder, and then, I guess, while packaging, it will "copy" them into lib folder... Ok!!!

Comment: Di Matteo: And it worked as you suggested. Everything is fine located in the lib folder once I export to war. So Cool! Thanks so much to you both, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is correctly configured as "Maven project" there should be a folder called "Maven Dependencies" in your package view. 
A good hint if your project is configured as Maven project is a little "M" on the top level folder. 
Eclipse will download in a so called "Repository". This is mostly located in `$HOME/.m2`

Generally you don't have to care about jars directly. Maven will download them and create a classpath transparently for you. 
The eclipse maven integration is called `m2e`.

The concept of Repositories is central to maven. They are the place where your dependencies and external dependencies are stored. Two repositories you can always assume to exist are the already mentioned local one and the other so called "Maven-Central" [see here](http://search.maven.org). Beside that you can setup , for example, company wide Repositories with tools like Nexus or Artifactory.

To upload a dependency in your local Repo use the `mvn install` command.
What maven within `mvn install` is executing the [install lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).
and then uploads the resulting artifact (generally a jar or war, but not necessarily) and some metadata (your pom mainly) to the repository.

You can then develop against these dependencies via the dependency mecahnism.

Dependencies in you installed in your local Repository are always of type "SNAPSHOT". There is more to know about the difference between SNAPSHOT and Release (only version number) and how to deploy/release them, but these questions are already awnsered several times.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jah.
In fact... I have check this out. While I was waiting for someone to answer my question, I already realized that all of my dependency jars was in fact in the position you point to: Maven dependencies. But this brings me to another question because I always thought that WEB-INF/Lib folder was the place to "place" all of my jars... and since I dind't find them on there, I guessed maven was not properly setup... But... if so... what about my internal jars? Do I need to place them in lib folder? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this plugin to pom.xml will help to get jars in lib folder.

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Wrong way...using maven-war-plugin and most important packaging war will automaticially do this...`WebContent` does not follow the default folder layout in Maven...